# Using the brightcove player in ActionScript over https

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, https, brightcove

I really need some help here, we are trying to use our player over https. I am detecting the protocol and then setting the secureConnections to true if it is https however it is still throwing a SecurityError, here is the setup code.

```
var config:Object = {};
        config.playerID = dataProxy.getDataResource(SettingsKeys.PLAYER_ID);
        config.labels = dataProxy.getStructureResource(SettingsKeys.LABELS_XML);
        config.width = videoPlayer.stage.stageWidth;
        config.height = videoPlayer.stage.stageHeight;
        config.secureConnections = LocationUtil.isHttps().toString();
        videoPlayer.configuration = config;
```

This is then passed to the player as such!

```
playerWrapper = new BrightcovePlayerWrapper(new BrightcovePlayer(_configuration));
```

When I get the security error I can actually see in the url that secureConnections=true why am I still getting a SecurityError when deploying to https and setting the required variable?

EDIT:

SecurityError: Error #2047: Security sandbox violation: parent: https://sadmin.brightcove.com/viewer/us20110817.1104/federatedVideoUI/BrightcovePlayer.swf cannot access https://mydomain.com/VideoTour/Application.swf.

I can confirm its loading the following crossdomain.xml from:

http://c.brightcove.com/crossdomain.xml

Comment: Care to paste the specifics of the error too? They might be useful.

Comment: could this be a problem with the crossdomain.xml?

Comment: thanks was cross domain problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a cross domain issue